# View different planes of a matrix with imagesc function

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a 3D matrix (48,64,190), How can I view the different planes independently:

1. XY plane
2. YZ plane
3. XZ plane

using `imagesc` or `image`?

[image: sample image]

Comment: There is no plane in a 3D matrix.  Please provide a small example of your input along with exact expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use reshape to reduce the dimensions of your data:

```
data = rand(48,64,190);

[sz1,sz2,sz3] = size(data);


f = figure;

% reshape not required
imagesc(data(:,:,140));

title('z=140');

h = figure;
imagesc(reshape(data(36,:,:), sz2, sz3));
title('x=36');

i = figure;

imagesc(reshape(data(:,47,:), sz1, sz3));
title('y=47');
```